# Noise when using Yealink SIP-T48G on AVM FritzBox 7580

Tags: voip, voice

I have a problem with a Yealink SIP-T48G connected to AVM FritzBox 7580.

Between the FritzBox and the phone is a Ubiquiti Unifi Dream Machine Pro. The FritzBox is the SIP server and the phone does not direct connect my provider. For many calls the phone and FritzBox work without problems, but for some calls there are strange noises and the subscriber is difficult or impossible to understand. On number with problems is 0697912290.

The sound is like [this](https://mk.catgirlsfor.science/files/67dab8bc-aab4-48fc-90f7-d7f9159cba4b).

I don't see any obvious errors in the RTP status either:

[image: RTP status page]

I have enabled the common codecs in the Yealink SIP-T48G:

- G722
- G726-24
- G726-32
- G726-40
- iLBC_13_33

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer using the tick icon - you may have to wait 48 hours though before you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Greenonline thank you for your edit, but the new codex name is not as in the GUI of the phone. The phone calls it `iLBC_13_33kbps`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. I did wonder, it was just because in your answer you put `iLBC_13_33` that I assumed it was a typo. Please feel free to correct my edit. Apologies :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by removing all codecs and only keeping `iLBC_13_33`.